# Very simple regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match something this:

```
<a space><any character/s>@<any character/s><a space>
```

Yes, it's a very very basic email parser.

Thanks!

Comment: `[.*]@[.*]` but it doesn't seem to work. I have no idea about regex :/

Comment: You should search around for e-mail addy regexes.  There are so many about.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There's something to be said for experimenting and learning. The e-mail address regexes out there are quite complex.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses (and [hundreds of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=email%20regex))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? `/^ [^@]+@[^ ]+ $/`

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets indicate a character class, which is the characters that can be present there. So, your regex would match `.@.` or `*@*`. Instead, try "`\ .*@.*\` " (quotes to show the space at the end, don't include them inside your regex.

Answer (score 0):

For testing e-mail, you might use the regex described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html):

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

It still doesn't cover 100% of e-mails, but the comprehensive version is [fairly involved](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: The Perl one isn't 100%: it is for an obsolete RFC and also requires pre-processing to remove comments.

Comment: That's true. One more log on the fire claiming that regular expressions might--just might--not be the end-all/be-all solution for testing whether or not an e-mail address is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
^ .+@.+ $
```

This translates to "the start of the string is followed by a space, one or more characters, the @ symbol, one or more characters, and the last character in the string is a space."